# MongoDB: "MongoSocketException: mongodb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to use Spring Boot with MongoDB for my Microservice architecture however when it's trying to connect it is giving me the below error;

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2020-03-31 16:45:34.909  INFO 18441 --- [}-mongodb:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

I'm using maven for the project and my pom.xml looks like this;

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Gosling-SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Finally I set up my application.yml which looks like this;

```
spring:
   data:
      mongodb:
         host: qwerty
         port: 27017
         username: user
         password: pw
         database: admin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the code you are using to try to connect to the MongoDB server. The exception is saying that there is something not right about the way you are trying to connect to the server; e.g., could be wrong connection string, etc.

Comment: It's just a spring boot application starter;

SpringBootApplication
EnableSwagger2
EnableMongoAuditing
public class AdminServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

Comment: All client applications connect to the MongoDB server using a connection string URI (including Spring data). See [ConnectionString URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html).

Comment: See the is about [Connecting to MongoDB with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-connectors).

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** Instead of using docker-compose, I run the image manually using the following command: `docker run -d -it -p 27017:27017 mongo`

*Connection confirmation*

[image]

*App is now connected*

[image]

---

**ISSUE:** I encountered a similar issue (as the error logs) and am not sure how to fix it:

Sharing my current settings...

*application.properties*

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:example@mongo_db:27017/`

*docker-compose content:*

```
mongo_db:
  image: mongo
  restart: always
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

mongo-express:
  image: mongo-express
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
  environment:
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo_db:27017/
```

*verifying the connectivity to the MongoDB server instance:*
[image]